# Get the max value of float numbers on a list on tuples?

Tags: python, list, max

i have the following list:

```
erra_eus_repo = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'), (u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.8'), (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'), (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]
```

what I am trying to take the `floating` point numbers from each `tuple`:

```
6.7, 6.8 ,7.2, 7.3
```

and get the max number for each version that before the dot .ie :

```
new_list = [ 6.8, 7.3 ]
```

Note that `max()` will not work here, since if I have 5.9 and 5.11, I will get the max as 5.9, I  want the result to be 5.11 since 11 > 9.

What I have tried:

```
eus_major = []
eus_minor = []
for major in erra_eus_repo:
    minor = (major[1][2])
    major = (major[1][0])
    if major not in eus_major:
            eus_major.append(major)

    if minor not in eus_minor:
            eus_minor.append(minor)
 print(eus_major, eus_minor)
```

currently i am getting:

```
[u'6', u'7'] [u'7', u'2', u'3']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for posting what you have tried so far.  Your code above has a few format errors in it (missing comma in `erra_eus_repo` and bad indent of the print statement). Moreover, your posted code doesn't yield the output you say it does.  It yields `['6', '7'] ['7', '8', '2', '3']`.  Also, the second value in your tuples isn't a floating point number, it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this for instance with a combination of `groupby` and sorting:

```
from itertools import groupby

srt_list = sorted(erra_eus_repo, key=lambda x: x[1]);

max_list = []
for key, group in groupby(srt_list, lambda x: x[1].split('.')[0]):
        max_el = max(list(group), key = lambda y: int(y[1].split('.')[1]))
        max_list.append(float(max_el[1]))
```

First the array is sorted based on second element of each tuple to get sequences of elements with matching non-decimal number for grouping with `groupby`. `groupby` groups the elements into just that - each group will represent a sequence X.Z with common X. In each of these sequences - groups the program finds the one with maximum decimal part treated as a stand-along number. The whole number is then appended to the list with max values as a float.

Comment: I knew that this could be done with `groupby` and was working on a solution similar to this but having difficulty. This is what I was aiming for, +1 **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Do not treat the version numbers as floating point, treat as '.' separated strings.  Then split each version string (split on '.') and compare.  Like this:

```
def normalize_version(v):
    return tuple(map(int, v.split('.')))
```

Then you can see:

```
>>> u'5.11' > u'5.9'
False

>>> normalize_version(u'5.11') > normalize_version(u'5.9')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on the problem which provides the highest value for each RHSA value (which is want I think you're after):

```
erra_eus_repo = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'), (u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.8'), (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'), (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]

eus_major = {}

for r in erra_eus_repo:

    if r[0] not in eus_major.keys():
        eus_major[r[0]] = 0

    if float(r[1]) > float(eus_major[r[0]]):
        eus_major[r[0]] = r[1]

print(eus_major)
```

output:

```
{'RHSA-2017:2796': '6.8', 'RHSA-2017:2794': '7.2', 'RHSA-2017:2793': '7.3'}
```

I left the value as a string, but it could easily be cast as a float.

Answer (score 0):

The following simply uses the built-in `min` and `max` functions:

```
erra_eus_repo = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'),
                 (u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.8'),
                 (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'),
                 (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]

eus_major = max(float(major[1])for major in erra_eus_repo)
eus_minor = min(float(major[1])for major in erra_eus_repo)
newlist = [eus_minor, eus_major]
print(newlist)  # -> [6.7, 7.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may look like you're trying to compare decimal values, but you really aren't.  It goes without saying (but I will) that while 9<11, .9>.11.  So the idea of splitting the number into two separate values is really the only way to get a valid comparison.

The list is a list of lists - you have the master and each has a sub-list of RHSA and a value.  Apparently you want discard the first item in the list and only get the (I assume) version of that item.  Here's some code that, while crude, will give you an idea of what to do.  (I'd welcome comments on how to clean that up...)  So I've taken the lists, split them, then split the versions into major and minor, then compared them and if nothing exists in the list, add the value.  I also added for sake of testing a 6.11 version number.

```
lstVersion = []
lstMaxVersion=[]
erra_eus_repo = [(u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.7'), (u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.8'), (u'RHSA-2017:2796', u'6.11'), (u'RHSA-2017:2794', u'7.2'), (u'RHSA-2017:2793', u'7.3')]
for strItem in erra_eus_repo:
    lstVersion.append(strItem[1])

for strVersion in lstVersion:
    blnAdded = False
    intMajor = int(strVersion.split('.')[0])
    intMinor = int(strVersion.split('.')[1])
    print 'intMajor: ', intMajor
    print 'intMinor:' , intMinor
    for strMaxItem in lstMaxVersion:
        intMaxMajor = int(strMaxItem.split('.')[0])
        intMaxMinor = int(strMaxItem.split('.')[1])
        print 'strMaxitem: ', strMaxItem
        print 'intMaxMajor: ', intMaxMajor
        print 'intMaxMinor: ', intMaxMinor
        if intMajor == intMaxMajor:
            blnAdded = True
            if intMinor > intMaxMinor:
                lstMaxVersion.remove(strMaxItem)
                lstMaxVersion.append(str(intMajor)+'.'+str(intMinor))
    if not blnAdded:
        lstMaxVersion.append(str(intMajor)+'.'+str(intMinor))
```